# C# binary tree loop trouble

Tags: c#, loops, infinite-loop, binary-search

I'm making a loop for searching a value from the array. If I find it, the position will be printed, if it's not "no such number" will be printed.
But, if I have several same numbers, I will receive only one and then I am over the loop. How can I get the control, if the same number in the array?
My best tries end with endless loop or completed loop from the start.

```
static public void Searching(int[] arr)
{
    string x = "yes";

    Console.WriteLine("Enter please searching number");
    while (x == "yes")
    {
        bool found = false;
        int target = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int searchkey = target;
        int mid = 0, first = 0, last = arr.Length - 1;
        while (!found && first <= last)
        {
            mid = (first + last) / 2;

            if (target == arr[mid])
                found = true;


            else
            {
                if (target > arr[mid])
                {
                    first = mid + 1;
                }

            if (target < arr[mid])
            {
                last = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    String foundmsg = found
                ? "Item " + searchkey + " was found at position " + mid
                : "Item " + searchkey + " was not found";
    Console.WriteLine(foundmsg);
    Console.WriteLine("would you like to find another number?");
    x = Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing English isn't your first language.  I'm honestly not sure why you're using a loop at all. If you convert your numbers array to a string, then use `.IndexOf(inputNumber)`, you'll have what you want.  Did I miss something on the language barrier?

Comment: You might want to reword your fist sentence as many find that word  offensive.

Comment: I just edited it out (and also did code formatting etc.) but now there is a pending edit. My edit goes out the window -_-

Comment: @cdove no that's fine, i know i could use that function, but that's my class task, so i should use only loops for that.

Comment: At first glance your code looks ok to me. Can you include the *input* that's causing you to get an infinite loop? Edit: are you saying if you have the same number multiple times you want to output the position of each of the matching numbers?

Comment: @aquinas in this case i dont have infinite loop.
For example i have 3 numbers of 20, but on screen will be only one twenty, so i need it's been shown three times, three different positions

Comment: Are you saying if you have the same number multiple times you want to output the position of each of the matching numbers? e.g., if you had 10,20,20,30 and I searched for 20 you want to output: "The key was found at position(s): 1,2"?

Comment: @aquinas yeah, you are absolutely right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Binary Search with sorted Array with duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197552/using-binary-search-with-sorted-array-with-duplicates)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to return all of the positions in the array where a particular value is found then create a list (like `List<int>`) and as you find the number in the array, add the position to the list. That way you can search the entire array without breaking out of your loop.

Then when you're done executing there will be either one or more items in the list or the list will be empty. If there are items in the list display those. If there are no items in the list return the "not found" message.

For example,

```
var indexes = new List<int>();
for(var index = 0; index < source.Length; index++)
{
    if(source[index] == target) indexes.Add(index);
}
```

When you're done you'll have either a list of matches or an empty list.

Lots of nested loops can get confusing. You have an outer loop that's handling the Console inputs. One way to make that easier to read is to isolate part into a function. For example,

```
List<int> GetIndexesOfMatchingNumbers(int[] source, int target)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    for(var index = 0; index < source.Length; index++)
    {
        if(source[index] == target) indexes.Add(index);
    }
}
```

You can call this function from your "main" function. It's functionally exactly the same but it reduces the amount of logic you have to follow when you read the code. That makes it easier to understand, even for the person writing it.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I keep methods to 15 lines or less (not counting spaces or lines with only braces.) Whether we're new or experienced, reading our own code or someone else's, it just makes it easier for the brain to process. It's usually easy to read a short function and tell what it's doing. Then we give that function a clear name, and it's easy to tell what we're doing - both in the function itself and wherever we call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop this.  C# has built in functions to help you.

```
static public void Searching(int[] arr)
    {
        string x = "yes";

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number for which to search...");
        int target = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        string Response = "Result of search is:"
        +  arr.IndexOf(target) != -1 
        ? arr.IndexOf(target).ToString() : "Not Found";
       //indexOf finds the first index of obj. in array
        Console.WriteLine(Response);
     }
```

This should satisfy your "when I find one of multiples I receive only one" requirement.  You'll always get the first occurrence.

If you need all instances, and use a loop, it's not all that different.

```
static public void Searching(int[] arr)
    {
        string x = "yes";

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number for which to search...");
        int target = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string result = string.Empty
        for(int i =0; i < arr.Length; i++)
              if (i = target)
              { result += i.ToString() + ", " }
        }
        if(result != string.Empty)
        {
           result = result.SubString(0, result.Length - 2);
           //removes extra space and colon
        } else {
           result = "Not Found";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Result of search is:"
        + result);
     }
```

Comment: I believe 1) it's for school and 2) he's trying to do a binary search. IndexOf isn't a binary search.

Comment: IndexOf finds the first instance. He's saying that the number could appear in the array more than once and he needs to return the position for each one.

Comment: But this doesn't satisfy the requirement (hidden in the comments): "but that's my class task, so i should use only loops "

Comment: Yeah I was writing this answer before he added that bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Array.BinarySearch` in order to find *some* item's index and then starting from the index move *backward* and *forward*:

```
  int[] source = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 15, 20 };

  int searchkey = 4;

  int first = -1;
  int last = -1;

  int index = Array.BinarySearch(source, searchkey);

  if (index >= 0) {
    first = index;
    last = index;

    for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (source[i] != toFind)
        break;
      else
        first = i;

    for (int i = index + 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
      if (source[i] != toFind)
        break;
      else
        last = i;

    if (first == last)
      Console.Write($"{searchkey} found at {first} position");
    else
      Console.Write($"{searchkey} found at [{first}..{last}] positions");
  }
  else
    Console.Write($"{searchkey} is not found");
```